# While I am retrieving my array of document in cloud firestore using Flutter I got error like list is not a sub type of string

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my dart code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'chewie_list_item.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);
    if (kReleaseMode) exit(1);
  };

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: CourseApp(),
  ));
}

class CourseApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Flutter Demo"),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection("courses").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot courses = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                return (ChewieListItem(
                  videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.network(
                      courses['video'] ?? 'default'),
                ));
              },
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

[This is the error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2INC.png) while running the app and [this is my firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwykU.png).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is causing the issue is that `courses['video']` is an array, as per what you shared in your screenshot of the firestore, and the VideoPlayerController.network() is expecting a string, so you have to either change that function, use a single value of that array or concatenate the values of the array into a single string, which is what I have done in this **untested** code, give it a try:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Flutter Demo"),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection("courses").snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        DocumentSnapshot courses = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                        var video = courses['video'];
                        var str = "";
                        video.foreach(value => {
                            str = str + value + ", "
                        })
                        // to remove the last ", "
                        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 2);
                        return (ChewieListItem(videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.network(str ?? 'default')));
                    },
                );
            },
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: I added this but I got my error list<dynamic> is not a subtype of string .

Comment: Got it, what is causing the issue is that `courses['video']` or `doc['video']` in my answer is an array, as per what you shared in your screenshot of the firestore, and the VideoPlayerController.network() is expecting a string, so you have to either change that function or only use a single value of that array. Let me know if this is it and I will change it into the answer.

Comment: I want full array from my firebase then what should I make a change in my code please tell me. So in short please provide me code that prints the whole array instead of calling one by one like the video[0] and video[1].

Comment: I edited the answer with what you asked, try it out, keep in mind that it's untested code, so it might need to be adapted, but that is the general idea.